# BubbleChart and BarChart in CombinedXYChart throws Exception

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm just trying to get run a BubbleChart combined with a BarChart in a CombinedXYChart, But i get always an Exception.
Here is my Code :

```
public class LineGraph extends AbstractDemoChart {
      private static final long HOUR = 3600 * 1000;
      private static final long DAY = HOUR * 24;
      private static final int HOURS = 24;

    public Intent getIntent(Context context,double[] personCount, Date[] timeValue) {


        XYValueSeries sunSeries = new XYValueSeries("Sunshine hours");
        /*Create XYSeries and fill it with 24 int Values for X-Axis and PersonCount for Y-Axis*/
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Test");
        for (int i = 0; i < timeValue.length; i++) {
            series.add(i, personCount[i]);
            sunSeries.add(i, 15, 4.3);
        }

        XYSeriesRenderer lightRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        lightRenderer.setColor(Color.YELLOW);

        // Creating a dataset to hold each series
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset =new XYMultipleSeriesDataset(); 
        dataset.addSeries(series);
        dataset.addSeries(0, sunSeries);


        // Now I create the Series renderer
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer =new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        //last step, Creating the renderer that controls the full charts and add the single renderer for each series 
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer =new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(0,lightRenderer);
        renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.SQUARE);
        renderer.setFillPoints(true);

        // Use DateFormatter for having X Labels in the form of HH:mm
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        for (int i = 0; i < timeValue.length; i++) {
            // add custom Labels with correct format
            if(i%2==0){
                mRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, formatter.format(timeValue[i]));     
            }
        }

        mRenderer.setYLabels(10);
        mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
        mRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);
        mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
        // disable the default labels
        mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
        mRenderer.setShowCustomTextGrid(true);
        mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
        mRenderer.setPanLimits(new double[] { -10, 20, -10, 40 });
        mRenderer.setZoomLimits(new double[] { -10, 20, -10, 40 });
        mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        mRenderer.setChartTitle("Persons");


        Intent intent = ChartFactory.getCombinedXYChartIntent(context, dataset, mRenderer,  new String[]{BarChart.TYPE, BubbleChart.TYPE},
                    "Weather parameters");
        return intent;
    }   
}
```

and the Exception i get is the following :

```
09-18 15:05:58.780: D/AndroidRuntime(14721): Shutting down VM
09-18 15:05:58.780: W/dalvikvm(14721): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a55700)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.achartengine.model.XYSeries cannot be cast to org.achartengine.model.XYValueSeries
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at org.achartengine.chart.BubbleChart.drawSeries(BubbleChart.java:75)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at org.achartengine.chart.XYChart.drawSeries(XYChart.java:518)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at org.achartengine.chart.CombinedXYChart.drawSeries(CombinedXYChart.java:140)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at org.achartengine.chart.XYChart.draw(XYChart.java:311)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at org.achartengine.GraphicalView.onDraw(GraphicalView.java:168)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14853)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13744)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13786)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14563)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3316)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3153)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13739)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13786)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14563)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3316)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3153)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13739)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13786)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14563)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3316)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3153)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14856)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2621)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13744)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13786)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.buildDisplayList(HardwareRenderer.java:1411)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1359)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2672)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2538)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2154)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6364)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
09-18 15:05:58.790: E/AndroidRuntime(14721):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I don't understand why this Exception is always thrown, 
I have tried to do it just like in the demo from AChartEngine.


Many thanks for help

Comment: I don't think your error is in the code you are showing here. Find a place in your code where you are passing `XYSeries` into a method that takes `XYValueSeries`. This will throw the exception you got. Double click on the stack trace in the error message (for example on `org.achartengine.chart.BubbleChart.drawSeries(BubbleChart.java:75)`. This will take you to where the error was caused and you can debug it better...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Changing

```
XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Test");
```

to

```
XYValueSeries series = new XYValueSeries("Test");
```

Comment: Hi , i have already tried both ways , with XYSeries and XYValueSeries, but i still get the same Exception.

Comment: Look here and file attached https://github.com/keshav-iitr/Achartengine/tree/Help and change values of this example for ur requirement.

Answer (score 0):

@keshav, it works fine, many thanks!
What is import to know is that i used the aChartEngine 1.1.0, but this Version has no XYCombinedChartDef. 
I had to Download the aChartEngine V 1.2.0 and with this Version everything works fine